# middleman less import problems, can't find assets

Tags: ruby, less, asset-pipeline, sprockets, middleman

I'm using [middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) with bower to manage bootstrap/less and other libraries and most everything i need works beautifully using:

```
after_configuration do
  sprockets.append_path File.join "#{root}", "components"
....
```

This works fine when I just want to require something from all.css

```
*= require bootstrap
```

Works great, but when I try to import libraries in less it can't seem to find them anywhere...

```
// bootstrap_and_overrides.less
// physical location is /components/bootstrap/less
@import "bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Nothing works, cannot find assets error... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

https://github.com/razorfly/middleman-bootstrap-template

Answer (score 1):

@import is the Less processor and not Sprockets.

What I did was reference the Bower components directory in the less file.

```
@import "../../components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap"
```

The Less compiler has no problems walking the directory tree, so give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should have sprockets activated in your config file.

```
activate :sprockets
```

It's kind of obvious but the template does not activate sprockets by default.

Comment: I added this in my config.rb and it did not fix the problem